# Can you use ObjectID's as the key of an array in MongoDb?

Tags: mongodb

I am currently in the process of designing one of my first mongo databases. I have a collection of users and those users have a list of preferences that they have defined for themselves. Here is a sample of an associate:

```
{
   _id : ObjectID,
   organization : "organization name",
   userID : "1234567",
   userPreferences : []
}
```

Basically I am trying to store associate communication preferences based off of different types of notifications that they may receive in my program. A user can determine that if a get x type of notification I want to be notified through a text and an email, but if I get y type of notification I only want a text message. I created a separate collection that stores properties of each notification type (x, y, etc) as shown below:

```
{
   _id : ObjectID,
   organization : "organization name",
   serviceCode : "22222",
   eventCode : "55555"
}
```

A combination of organization, serviceCode, and eventCode define a unique notification type. I wish to have a list in my user collection that store the user's perfered notification method for different notification types. Something like the following:

```
userPreferences : [
   NotificationID1 : [TEXT, EMAIL],
   NotificationID2 : [TEXT]
]
```

Where the NotificationID's correlate to the ObjectID of the notification type collection. What is the best way to accomplish this in mongo?

Comment: Array - no, it doesn't have "keys". You need an object/subdocument here.